# Click event button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

as you can see the picture and code included. how can i make it like when the Available button is clicked it will change the text to the Username of the account who clicked it.

[image]

```
<li>0 - 1  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnD" data-loading-text="Username">Available</button>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        $('#btnD').click(function(){
                    var btn = $(this);
                    btn.button('loading');
        });
});
</script></li>
<li>0 - 2</li>
<li>0 - 3</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/hgnyqfoj/

```js
var username = "James Balogbog"
$('#btnD').click(function(){
 $(this).text(username);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnD" data-loading-text="Username">Available</button>
```

In the solution, I made an **assumption** that username will be available with  you throughout your code, so I created a variable named username.

Using the created variable (**username**) updated the **text** of the **button** in **onclick** **event**.